# Force the browser to download file as CSV from url

Tags: javascript, csv

I am downloading a CSV file from a URL how do I set certain response headers to download my file

**Desired response headers:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 29 May 2017 06:03:38 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 340
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon May 29 11:33:38 IST 2017
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="5756913MerchantTransactionFile20170529113338.csv"
Server: Some
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 
authorized: true
authorizehtml: true
```

**Current response headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 29 May 2017 06:16:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) PHP/5.5.36
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token
Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon May 29 11:46:52 IST 2017
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=97
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

**My code:**

```
openFile(url) {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

    }
};
xhttp.open("GET",url, true);
xhttp.send();
  //window.open(url, '_blank')
}
```

Trying to download a csv file from the url. Please help me out. How do we force the browser to download a file.

Comment: How are you serving he supposed csv file? Response headers can only be set by the responding agent.

Comment: The **response** headers are what the **server** is telling your client. Only thing you can change from the client is the **request** headers that might cause a different response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trick here is to convert your data into blob  and simulate a click event on an anchor tag with blob url.

`var blob = new Blob([content]);`

create an click event

```
var evnt =  new Event('click');
```

then create an anchor tag as follows and dispatch event

```
  $("<a>", {
    download: filename,
    href: webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob)
  }).get(0).dispatchEvent(evnt);
```

Here is a function

```
 var download = function(filename, content) {
  var blob = new Blob([content]);
  var evnt =  new Event('click');

  $("<a>", {
    download: filename,
    href: webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob)
  }).get(0).dispatchEvent(evnt);
};
```

Use the above download function.

USAGE: call the function download with two parameters `filename` and `content`

```
openFile(url) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      download('file.csv', data);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
  //window.open(url, '_blank')
}
```

Comment: Why an custom event ? (and this without saying that your way of creating one is deprecated and that you don't even init it correctly).  Why create an Blob from the xhr response when you've got `xhr.responseType = 'blob'` option ? What about browsers that don't support `Anchor.download` attribute ?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I have added the newer approach to add event. Also, this method is not just specific to `xhr` it can take a normal text content and help download it. thats why the blob conversion in inside the function. And this approach is for most newer major browser and it has 73% usage and the question is not browser specific.

Answer (score -1):

You should specify correct Accept header when making a request. Then server, in response, will put the correct Content-Type header. In your case you should add this line when creating XMLHttpRequest:

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/csv; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: It is not a question of accepting `text/csv` but its a question of forcing download dialog which is caused by `Content-Disposition` response header.

Comment: @Vivek, there's no mention about dialog. There is only question about incorrect response header. Asking person tries to fix somehow headers from server. I offered possible solution. It's a server who should specify Content-Disposition header and Content-Type.

Comment: The question title itself contains `Force the browser to download file`